# Move a PostgreSQL Data Directory to a New Location on 3.1 usb flash drive

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-18.04

after having mounted the disk, stopped PostgreSQL, I run the following command:

```
sudo rsync -av /var/lib/postgresql /media/usb
```

It copies lots of files, but in the end, I get (a lot more of these errors in fact)

```
rsync: chown "/media/usb/postgresql/12/main/pg_wal/.0000000100000061000000AF.rLqTrQ" failed:   Operation not permitted (1)
rsync: chown "/media/usb/postgresql/12/main/pg_wal/.0000000100000061000000B0.pFnk6j" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
rsync: chown "/media/usb/postgresql/12/main/pg_xact/.0000.zOYtkr" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
rsync: chown "/media/usb/postgresql/12/main/pg_xact/.0001.zuvjGO" failed: Operation not permitted (1)

sent 16,969,375,749 bytes  received 177,882 bytes  17,947,703.47 bytes/sec
total size is 16,965,154,821  speedup is 1.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]
```

I have no idea what is happening and was wondering if anyone could help?

Thanks,

Pierre.

Comment: Perhaps the USB stick has a file system that has problems with dot files.

Comment: Any idea how to find out?